# jQuery inserting children first when using append() instead of last

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, append

I'm having trouble inserting child elements to a list in HTML using jQuery. I'm a beginner when it comes to anything JavaScript related so my code is probably very clunky and unoptimized. Even if you can't help me with the original issue I always appriciate pointers to improve my code and learn.

I have a function that runs every second (it's called from my CefSharp application, not sure if it's relevant). This is my function:

```
function updateOrderQueue(index, reference, pickedup, deliveredto, robotId, statuscode, statustext) {
    var list = $('#orderQueueList');
    var count = $("#orderQueueList li").length;

    if (!document.getElementById('order' + reference) && statuscode < 4 && count < 10) {
        var data = $(`<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center border border-dark" id="order` + reference + `">
                        <h3 class="mt-1" id="text`+ reference + `">
                            [`+index+`] `+ pickedup + ` ➔ ` + deliveredto + ` (` + statustext +  `)
                        </h3>
                        <small class="badge badge-dark rounded" style="font-size:24px;" id="robotQueue`+ reference + `">` + robotId + `</small>
                    </li>`);
        list.append(data).hide().fadeIn(500);
    } else {
        var locations = jQuery("#text" + jq(reference));
        var assignedrobot = jQuery("#robotQueue" + jq(reference));

        locations.text('['+index+'] '+ pickedup + ' ➔ ' + deliveredto + ' (' + statustext + ')');
        assignedrobot.text(robotId);
    }

    var elems = $('#orderQueueList li').detach().sort(function (a, b) {
        if (isNaN($(a).text()) || isNaN($(b).text())) {
            return $(a).text() > $(b).text() ? 1 : -1;
        }
        return $(a).text() - $(b).text();
    });
    list.append(elems);
}
```

And this is the HMTL code

```
<div id="orderQueue" class="">
   <ul class="list-group" id="orderQueueList">
   </ul>
</div>
```

I'm going to try to quickly explain what I intend on it doing and what it actually does.

So basically, this code is supposed to **add**, **sort** and **add relevant classes** to items in a list. To be added, the item needs to pass a set of requirements (not already added, statuscode under 4 and not more than 10 items total). I then append the item into the list, which I assumed would put it at the end of the list (compared to prepend, which should do the opposite).

The problem is, whenever a new item is added, it is added to the top of the list. My guess is that is has something to do with the fact that I'm appending it to the **ul**. I tried doing something like **$('#orderQueueList li:last')** but I didn't get it to work. I've also tried to do **$('#orderQueueList).children()** and **$('#orderQueueList).last()** before appending without success.

What am I missing? Have I completely misunderstood what append does? Have I written the code wrong?

Appriciate any pointers,

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's easy enough to confirm that ,.append() in isolation puts new elements at the end:  https://jsfiddle.net/ze6kg9dj/   So what's different in your code - you should reduce your code to just the relevant parts (is all that addclass/removeclass code relevant?) ideally in a *complete* snippet that *demonstrates* the issue.  See [mcve].

Comment: Are you sure it's not the sort that's resorting it to the top?  Try add a `return` just before `var elems = $('#orderQueueList li').detach()` to rule that out.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you, I'll edit that and think about it until next time. I don't think it's the sort as this problem existed earlier aswell. I forgot to show you my HTML code though, I'll add it to the question aswell. I'm going to try and see what the return gives me.

Comment: @freedomn-m I cannot believe it was the sort function. I guess I excluded that from the possible scenarios because it managed to sort the items in the end. Why does my sort function resort them back to the top and then again successfully sort them to the bottom (depending on the index)?

Comment: Possibly relevant (probably not): `list.append(data).hide().fadeIn(500);` will hide the entire `ul` and fade it in, not just the newly appended element.  It may be affecting your sort.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thought about that. Removed the hide and fadeIn but the result is still the same. Does it have anything to do with the fact that is sorts according to the text? I feel like it shouldn't matter but maybe it does? Is there any other way of sorting lists that would be to prefer? Could I sort purely based on the index without changing the ID of the list item (I need the ID to be the reference of the order)?

Comment: Sorting by the index would not change the sort order.

Comment: Your sort works fine, but it *is* **affected by whitespace**, compare: https://jsfiddle.net/ze6kg9dj/1/ with https://jsfiddle.net/ze6kg9dj/2/  try adding a `.trim()` https://jsfiddle.net/ze6kg9dj/3/

Comment: @freedomn-m That worked! Thank you! Put it as an answer so I can upvote and check it! Would you also have any pointers/tips on how I can solve the sorting for numbers above 9? (15 for example is treated as being a lower number than 9 because of sorting through text).

Comment: Your code already mitigates sorting numbers as text with `isNaN($(a).text()` which already ignored leading whitespace.   If there's *other* text (other than numbers/whitespace) or whitespace in the middle) then isNaN will be true (not a number).   You could convert to integer (either `parseInt()` which stops at the first non-number (except leading whitepace) or `(....text() * 1)` to convert to an int then check if both == 0 and do text comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is not the `.append()` but the `.sort()` which comes after.

Sorting text is affected by whitespace, so the solution is to `.trim()` the text when doing a text comparison:

```js
$("ul").append("<li>new</li>").hide().fadeIn(500);
var elems = $('ul li').detach().sort(function(a, b) {
  if (isNaN($(a).text()) || isNaN($(b).text())) {
    return $(a).text().trim() > $(b).text().trim() ? 1 : -1;
  }
  return $(a).text() - $(b).text();
});
$("ul").append(elems);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>   2</li>
  <li>1555</li>
  <li>xyz</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>
  abc
  </li>
</ul>
```